# Springboot BindingResult hasErrors is always false

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, validation

I have tried all the answer I have found on internet and nothing seems to be working.

I have added hibernate-validation, spring validation but both are not working and bindingResult.haserrors() is always false.

Dependencies I am using currently in my project

```
javax.validation:validation-api:2.0.1.Final
org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:6.0.18.Final
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:2.1.13.RELEASE
com.github.java-json-tools:json-schema-validator:2.2.8
io.springfox:springfox-bean-validators:2.9.2
```

Controller

```
public String processRequest(
      @ApiParam(value = "Input JSON",
          required = true)  @Valid @RequestBody MyClass myClass,
      BindingResult results) {
if (results.hasErrors()) {
      List<FieldError> fieldErrors = results.getFieldErrors();
      throw new InvalidFieldException(fieldErrors);
    }
}
```

MyClass

```
public class MyClass {


  @NotBlank
  @Size(min = 1, max = 80)
  private String firstName;

  @Size(max = 80)
  private String middleName;

  @NotBlank
  @Size(min = 1, max = 80)
  private String lastName;


}
```

I am call controller using this myClass Object

```
MyClass myClass =
        MyClass.builder().firstName("linus").lastName("").build();
```

Can someone please help me?

Comment: More information is needed, such as validated objects, how validation is triggered. Please include some code and not only some dependencies.

Comment: @JoãoDias edited and added more code

Comment: Explicitly calling a Controller class is already weird enough, but let us assume you are doing this for testing purposes. Who is calling the Controller method? Have you tried adding `@Validated` to your Controller?

Comment: @JoãoDias I am calling from test class usnig MockMvc.

mockMvc.perform(post("/url").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)).andExpect(status().is4xxClientError());

Comment: I assume that is an `@WebMvcTest` right?

Comment: Can you please add the complete code of the Controller and also the Test?